# Is it possible to configure edge full-screen speed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-11, microsoft-edge, fullscreen

When you press F11 on the Edge browser to show the sites in full screen, if the mouse hovers over the top border, the address bar shows up and takes a lot to hide back. How can we make it hide/show up immediately with the Windows registry, browser flags, program, or in any other way?
The solution could be for Windows 10 or Windows 11.

Comment: You can use Alt-D to make it appear immediately (and Esc to then dismiss it), if that's what you mean.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks! However if hovering normally, it still hides the page for two seconds. Are you able to simply configure it somehow to avoid this and also avoid pressing key combinations every time?

Comment: I have the opposite question: After accidentally touching the border, it takes several seconds for the address bar to disappear again. So how can I make it disappear immediately after leaving the border ? There might be a common answer for both questions ...

Comment: Yes, it's so annoying and counter-productive

Comment: Are you looking for the [Full Screen Drop Down](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-full-screen-drop-down-ui-in-microsoft-edge/)?

Comment: No, sorry. That article was published in 2020 and now the behavior described there is the default one. The drop down UI is taking way too long to react, and we are looking for a way to configure that delay to 0.

Comment: I can only think of restricting the mouse from passing over the top border.

Comment: We want the menus to show up and also to hide, but we need that to happen immediately without delay.

Answer (score 3):

That is not currently configurable through any browser flag or any registry change that I know.

However, it could be possible to do with an [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/index.htm) script that detects when the mouse hits the top screen border while on the Edge browser and triggers an F4 keypress. On the other side, if the mouse leaves the address bar area, the script could trigger an Shift + F6 keypress to hide the bar immediately as requested. Use [CoordMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/CoordMode.htm), [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetTimer.htm) and [MouseGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/MouseGetPos.htm).

Comment: Shift-F6 seems to be a useful workaround for me to hide the the address bar (and the vertical tab bar) again after the mouse pointer touched the border accidentally.

Comment: But in fact, Shift-F6 works only if the focus is in the address bar which is not the case if the address bar did appear after the pointer touched the border by accident. So Shift-F6 is in fact not a useful workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The **only** current settings relating to the MS Edge UI fullscreen dropdown (Shy UI) are:

- Disable/enable ShyUI entirely
- Enable swipe-down gesture for touch devices to trigger the UI in fullscreen mode
- Settings > Appearance > Toolbar, for options like vertical tabs or whether to show favorites, which can shrink/increase toolbar size quite a bit
- In Windows > View advanced system settings > Advanced > Performance > Settings, you can disable "Animate controls and elements inside windows" to cut out the edge toolbar slide animation

The UI basically starts a 1-second timer as soon as the mouse stops moving, which restarts if the mouse moves again. It will not hide while the mouse is still active, so it *can* take forever if you're the type of person to wiggle the mouse.